# Changing the type of a variable in strict mode

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, strict-mode

Whilst taking a quiz on PluralSight about JavaScript, I came across this question:

> **Assuming you've enabled strictness, can you change the type of a variable once defined?**
>
> - Yes, without restriction
> - Yes, but you have to redefine the variable
> - No

The *correct* answer was **No**. Perhaps I've understood the question wrong, but to me it suggests that the following code would be invalid:

```
function test() {
    "use strict";
    let x = 12; // x is a number
    x = "hello world"; // x is now a string
    return x;
}
console.log(test());
```

A quick test in Chrome, Firefox and Edge runs the above code perfectly fine. I've also looked at Annex C in the [ECMAScript 2016 spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) (assuming that's the correct document) and have found no mention on restricting the type of a variable in strict mode there.

Have I missed or misunderstood something here, or is the question flawed or perhaps misleading?

Comment: (D) None of the above. The premise of the question is invalid because JS variables don't have a type, *values* have a type.

Comment: @nnnnnn completely agree, the question made no sense at all to me. Which is why I thought perhaps it was poorly worded and I misunderstood what the question was intending to ask.

Comment: I agree with @nnnnnn the question has no sense or a bug in it :)

Comment: @GibboK Rather no sense *and* a bug in it!!!

Answer (score 3):

The question is not clear without context. What do they mean by "variable" and what do they mean by "type"?

They could refer to anything, though usually we understand that phrase as short for "*the type of the value(s) that the variable (currently) holds*", (though "type" itself is ambiguous, meaning either Type or `typeof`) - and of course most variables can change their values and their type.
It might have referred to properties of the variable itself - e.g. its mutability, the kind of the binding, the scope (record) in which it is stored - which usually do not change.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no context. Each question is isolated and there was no code or additional information in the question

Comment: Yes, it's just a bad question with sloppy, unclear language. We don't "enable strictness" or "define variables" either.

Answer (score 0):

> Here x is a global variable, outside function it always return the global variable value.
>   You can't re-declared a variable using **let**keyword within the same scope but in another scope you can do, that may be strict or not

```
function test() {
    "use strict";
    let x = 12; // x is a number  
    //let x = "hello world"; // you can't do like this
    return x;
}
        let x = "hello world"; // its ok
console.log(test());
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think the question is talking about re-declaring a variable or variable scope. I think the question is talking talking about assigning a new value of a different type to a previously declared variable.